# goto(url, {waitFor: 'load'}) function in puppeteer never resolves even though page.readyState === 'complete'

Tags: navigation, puppeteer, readystate

Using puppeteer: 1.3.0

Puppeteer navigates to the page using `goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'load'})`.

It then never resolved simply leaving me on the page. I can open the console in the dev tools and type in `document.readyState` and get `"completed"`.

Anyone have any idea why `goto` is not resolving?

readyState documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

**EDIT**

1. Changed `waitFor` to `waitUntil`
2. After further investigation I've realized that the problem is in fact with the web page I am on. The navigation does not trigger any [lifecycle events](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded) which is what the goto() method relies on in order to complete.

Comment: Seems to work in this [demo](https://puppeteersandbox.com/U5KqyOkY). Can you provide a repro in puppeteersandbox?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [original API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), The correct syntax/argument for the loading confirmation is `waitUntil` and not `waitFor`.

```
goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'load'})
```